# EbaySDK using reference missing even after install package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have installed a NuGet package called EbaySDK by ebay on my project. But problem is still cant use following using reference

```
using eBay.Service.Call;
using eBay.Service.Core.Sdk;
using eBay.Service.Util;
using eBay.Service.Core.Soap;
```

You can check [image: picture1] and [image: picture2] for better understanding. Any idea with EbaySDK usage? What mistake i am doing here? A sample usage of that SDK document also available here [SDK Document](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1681)

Comment: Verify that the ebay libraries are in the Reference, first.  Sometimes the NuGet packages are not "cleanly" developed and the libraries never make it to the References location.

Comment: Just tried it with the NuGet-Console (`install-package ebaysdk`) and I can use the references just fine. As @GoldBishop suggested, check if `eBay.Service` shows up under References.

Comment: bro you are correct. working now. you can answer it @waka

Comment: On a side note, this content is poor. Your case is trivial but still, you are asking a question heavily enviroment-dependable and haven't specified your setup/platform at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP:

It seems that the needed references never made it to the references location. If this happens, try installing the NuGet package via the console.

You may have to uninstall it first:

```
uninstall-package ebaysdk
```

And then:

```
install-package ebaysdk
```

Check the references of your project. Does `ebay.Service` show up? If so, you are ready to go. If not, you can try adding the reference manually. It should get downloaded to your project folder into the subfolder *packages*. For example:

> \YourProject\packages\eBaySDK.3.805.0\lib\net40\eBay.Service.dll

You can add it via *Add Reference...* and then manually navigating to the folder.