# The type or namespace name 'Devart' could not be found

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am having problems with this. I installed Devart.Data.MySql package from NuGet, but when I try to call `using Devart.Data.MySql;` namespace, I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Devart' could not be found
```

I need to use the `MySqlDependancy`, however I know I need this using Directive Namespace but I just can't get it to work.

Someone mentioned updating Devart assemblies in the project/website, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: If you look under `YourProject -> References` in the project explorer, do you see the Devart assembly listed in the references? If not, you may have to reinstall it again, preferrably using the NuGet console, as I've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365629/2099119).

Comment: @waka I uninstalled Devart.Data.MySql, and then installed it back but nothing happened. Also I am creating a website, and I don't have a references folder under project, but I can find references using the quick launch and add a new one if that wold help.

Comment: @waka I can't find a reference with the name Devart or Devart.Data.MySql

Comment: No reference folder? In my asp projects I still have that folder. :( Can you try adding the reference manually as you suggested in your other comment?

Comment: @waka I tried to add the reference but I can't find  Devart or Devart.Data.MySql. I checked if I can add other references such as MySql.Data and it works fine.. but no Devart  to be found. Do you know how to make MySqlDependancy or Devart.Data.MySql work?

Comment: Nope, sorry. :(

Comment: @waka no worries, thank you :).